# drag and drop with target

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop

I am kinda new in flash as3, however am doing courseware app that involves dragging words into their appropriate targets with scores if correctly matched and also includes a 20sec timer that an exercise should be done. But my problem is after i drag the words correct to their positions and get relevant score (I use 10 marks each correct answer) still I can drag the word and score again and again using every dragged word (i.e I want to unable dragged words from dragging) which makes a user to score more exceeding the higher score (i.e 90 marks because there 9 words to drag).

Here is my coding;

```
 stop();    
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;   
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;    
    import flash.utils.Timer;    
    var myscore1 = 0;  score.text = myscore1+"";

    var hitArray:Array = new Array(love_tgt, am_stud_tgt, living_tgt, is_improv_tgt, speak_tgt,
                                   means_tgt, are_help_tgt, want_tgt, miss_tgt);    
    var dropArray:Array = new Array(love, am_stud, living, is_improv, speak, means, are_help,
                                    want, miss);    
var positionsArray:Array = new Array();

    for (var i:int = 0; i < dropArray.length; i++) {
         dropArray[i].buttonMode = true;
         dropArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mdown);
         dropArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);

         positionsArray.push({xPos:dropArray[i].x, yPos:dropArray[i].y});
    }

    function mdown(e:MouseEvent):void {
        e.currentTarget.startDrag();
        setChildIndex(MovieClip(e.currentTarget), numChildren - 1);
    }

    function mUp(e:MouseEvent):void {   
    var dropIndex:int = dropArray.indexOf(e.currentTarget);   
    var target:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;    
    target.stopDrag();

        if (target.hitTestObject(hitArray[dropIndex])) {
                myscore1+=10;
                score.text = myscore1+""; 

                target.x = hitArray[dropIndex].x;
                target.y = hitArray[dropIndex].y;
            }else{
               target.x = positionsArray[dropIndex].xPos;
               target.y = positionsArray[dropIndex].yPos;
            }    
    }


    var myTimer1:Timer = new Timer(1000);    
    myTimer1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownHandler1);    
    function  countdownHandler1(event:TimerEvent):void{       
    countdown.text = 20-myTimer1.currentCount+" s remaining";
             if(myTimer1.currentCount==20){
                gotoAndStop(46);
             }      }  

      myTimer1.start();


    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. I just tried editing this mess, but I'm afraid to break something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still can drag the objects because they still have event listeners. All you need to do is to remove it.

```
if (target.hitTestObject(hitArray[dropIndex])) {
      myscore1+=10;
      score.text = myscore1+""; 

       target.x = hitArray[dropIndex].x;
       target.y = hitArray[dropIndex].y;

       //add these 2 lines---------------------------------------------
       target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mdown);
       target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);
       //--------------------------------------------------------------
 }else{
      target.x = positionsArray[dropIndex].xPos;
      target.y = positionsArray[dropIndex].yPos;
 }
```

Comment: Thanx so much brother Richard it works as planned, nevertheless i"m thinking to make the words be dragged to any target without bouncing (i.e disable bouncing) so that a student cannot get a mark by just trying. Is there a way to do this? just from same coding

Comment: you should look at Tween class. you can do the bouncing with just 1 line of code

Comment: Actually am not an outstanding programmer bro, may plz help me with this from my coding i put above? i will appreciate thanx bro Richard

Comment: Nope, do your research and try it yourself. Make some effort. I'll help you after you tried it